# fwrite if text doesn't exist in file?

Tags: php, symfony4

How to write in a file text if text doesn't exist and if already exists it continue for other part of text.
I have also to delete text in some conditions (if $data['y'] pass from 1 to 0)
Thank you.

```
 foreach ($x['data1']['alarms2'] as $data){

         if ($data['y']==1){
            $new_file= "test.txt";    
            $file = fopen($new_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file: '.$my_file);
            fwrite($file, '....');
            fclose($file); 
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "a+" modificator, instead of "w":

```
$new_file= "test.txt";    
$file = fopen($new_file, 'a+') or die('Cannot open file: '.$my_file);
fwrite($file, '....');
fclose($file);
```

Comment: if i use this to not rewrite the same thing,but for the delete if condition pass to 0 how to do it ?

Comment: @M.elabdallah well then use either mode `w` or `a+`, depending on what `$data['y']` contains …?

Comment: @misorude data contains a y that has value 1 or 0

Comment: @M.elabdallah yes, I know, you said that already in your initial question. I was simply trying so advise you on what you should do.